# Guardar imágenes en Storage de Laravel-8

Tags: laravel-8, filesystem, storage

Tengo una aplicación en L8, configuré un disk para utilizarlo en el Storage;

```
'avatars' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/private/images/avatars'),
],
```

Luego creé el link correspondiente

```
'links' => [
    public_path('avatars') => storage_path('app/private/images/avatars'),
],
```

Luego, en mi controlador, guardo el archivo en el Storage;

```
public function cambiarAvatar(Request $request)
{
    $path = Storage::disk('avatars')->put('imagen.jpg',$request->file('avatar'));

    return $path;
}
```

El inconveniente con este código, es que me crea un directorio llamado imagen.jpg, es decir, app/private/images/avatars/algo.jpg/... y el nombre del archivo una vez subido es el temporal;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían indicarme que puedo estar haciendo mal?, yo necesito poder guardar un archivo con el nombre que yo le indique, en el directorio establecido en el disk, es decir en app/private/images/avatars.

Mil gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema viene de como le pasas el segundo parámetro a el método `put()` ya que este debería ser **el contenido** en crudo del archivo, como dice [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files) en su documentación:

> El método `put` se puede utilizar para almacenar el contenido de un
> archivo en un disco. También puede pasar un `resource` **PHP** al
> método `put`, que utilizará el soporte de flujo subyacente de
> **Flysystem**. Recuerde, todas las rutas de archivo deben especificarse en relación con la ubicación "raíz" configurada para el
> disco

Y tu le estas pasando el archivo completo. Entonces deberías hacer algo como esto:

```php
$path = Storage::disk('avatars')->put( 'imagen.jpg', file_get_contents($request->file('avatar')->getPathName()) );
```

Usando la función [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) de **PHP**. Aunque te resultaría mucho mas sencillo usar el método [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files) de **Laravel** así:

```
$request->avatar->storeAs('', 'imagen.jpg', 'avatars');
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, efectivamente ambas opciones me resultaron bien, gracias de vuelta.

Comment: Con todo gusto..!!